# How to print data's along with background image in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey I am new to php and other stuffs. Now I am trying to make automatic bill creating page. But the problem is the background is not visible in print preview.

When I press the print button on the top left corner of the php page it shows a page without background image, at the same time I don't need print button in the print preview page. If I use `<img>` tag to insert image I can't able to display datas above the image.

My code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Page 1</title>
        <script language="javascript">
        function printpage()
            {
                window.print();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body background="Geekay.jpg">
        <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printpage();">
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        Datas....
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be interested in media queries to have css styles that only apply when you want to print the page. In these styles, you may hide the _print_ button, add a forced background, etc: http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Comment: Avoid things like <body background="Geekay.jpg"> and use CSS instead. Separating HTML from formatting is a good practise.

Comment: You have to save the image in somewhere for use it then with a url in your url() in style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing datas along with background image in print window click more settings (in case of google chrome). Then check background graphics. For not showing print button, I updated my code as given below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Page 1</title>
    <script language="javascript">
    function printpage()
        {
            document.getElementById('print').style.display = 'none';
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<form name="bill">
<body background="Geekay1.JPG">
<div id="print" style="display:block">  
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printpage()">
</div>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    Datas....



</body>
</form>
</html>
```